# Hive - How can I store the hive query results to be referred later?

Tags: hive, putty, hiveql, hadoop2

I usually connect to gateway node through putty and run hive queries over there.

On several occasions the queries run for hours together. And at least a few times, putty gets disconnected, and the execution of the queries also abort.

Is there a way to store hive query results somehow, so that I can inspect them at later points of time?

I don't want to create another table just to store the results.

Comment: So, basically, you want to run your query in the background and dump the results in text files? There are utilities like `nohup`and `batch` that have been around for at least 40 years... For instance `nohup hive -e "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wtf" 2>$HOME/query.log 1>$HOME/query.out &`

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter: Sorry I did a blunder, I updated the question. Query aborts on putty disconnect. Your answer is useful though! Thanks.

Comment: You can also avoid the PuTTY step altogether, **if** you have HiveServer2 running on your cluster, **if** there is no firewall preventing your PC to connect to the HS2 machine on port 10000, and **if** you don't use Hive CLI variables --> install DBVisualizer or a similar utility, install a Hive JDBC driver *(preferably the Cloudera driver, it's a free download; the Apache driver requires a smorgasbord of additional JARs, has no compatibility assurance versus older HiveServer2 versions, and is a nightmare to configure with Kerberos authentication)*, and run the queries straight from your PC.

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter: Thanks. I used Hue which in turn is configured to use HS2.

Comment: I'm not a great fan of Hue for several reasons *(the user interface is rather clusmsy, older versions used to crash on non-Ascii characters, and the python code vomits a lot of awkward logs server-side)*. It you are happy with Hue, fine. But if you expect to spend a lot of time on it, you might want to try a "real" database tool.

Answer (score 2):

You  can store your result

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'outputpath' SELECT * FROM table
```

Comment: Will the query  continue to run if putty disconnects? Thanks.